# Software for snowballing (data mining) academic papers

Tags: bibliometrics

Snowballing is a methods of data mining. In this method, a literature contains references. By using some keyword/keywords I would like extract those papers alone. I would again go to the references of the extracted papers and then using keyword/keywords, I would extract few more papers. This goes on and on till I converge.

I would like know is there any stand-alone software for this?

Comment: Such a software would need to have all the papers loaded into a database and linked the references to the right paper. As citation styles differ, that alone is quite a task. There might be something running on existing paper databases (e.g. google scholar), but if you want a stand alone, you first need to physically download all the papers and link them together. And if you do that, you can also just write the whole software from scratch, would be about the same amount of work.

Comment: Once I have tried to do something like that, I wanted to draw a network of papers and their citation relations, but I gave up. However, I think the way to go is to use data from Scopus or Web of Science, they provide some kind of API to access the data, so you can write a script to get it and then analyze it in what ever way you want.

Comment: The named Web of Science API might cost additional money (on top of the pure access fee). Talk to your library (or who else licenced Web of Science for you) about it or contact Web of Science directly.

Comment: So basically Google Scholar?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any such software available, and I doubt it would produce anything useful for the following reason:

> This goes on and on till I converge.

Without any restriction such an approach would probably not converge, at least not before reaching a few millions papers since it would follow citations across fields. Even with restrictions, you're likely to end up with a vast amount of data which would be very hard to exploit manually.